# Inlinig code in .asm file in 64 bit mode

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly, inline-code

I just wondered if it is possible to inline assembly functions written in an external .asm file. My application is in 64 bit mode so there is no way to use inline assembler (I am using Visual Studio C++).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can take a look here and see if it helps: https://universalbri.wordpress.com/2016/09/17/using-inline-x64-assembler-with-a-visual-c-windows-forms-based-application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in theory using Link Time Code Generation, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbf3tbeh.aspx)

When /LTCG is used to link modules compiled by using /Og, /O1, /O2, or /Ox, the following optimizations are performed:

- Cross-module inlining

...

Not sure if it will work in practice though...

Comment: There isn't any C source for the compiler to "understand", so it won't know how to mix the asm into parent functions.  I highly doubt LTCG can do anything for asm source files other than still `call` them the normal way.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio does not allow inline assembly in 64 bit mode.

Comment: isn't there any way to achieve inlining in any other way?

Comment: @Philinator: Not that I know of.

Comment: To be clear, you can write 100% asm routines and then call them from 64bit c code.  They just won't be inlined.